# Error while making axios call when passing value of url and payload in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I am using react native app, and have a api calling functionality.

```
import axios from 'axios';
const getPayload = (payload: any | FormData, isFormData = false) => {
  if (isFormData) {
    return payload;
  } else {
    return {...payload};
  }
};

export default {
  post: async (
    url: string,
    payload = {},
  ): Promise<any> => {      
    payload = getPayload(payload);
        console.log("url: ",url)
        console.log("payload: ", payload);
        
    axios.post('https://url.com/user/login', {"email": "email@gmail.com", "password": "123456"})
        .then((resp: any)=> {
            console.log("resp here: ",JSON.stringify(resp.data));;
            
        })
        .catch((err: any)=> {
            console.log("err here: ", err);
            
        });
    // return getRequestPromise(request);
  },
};
```

If I am doing like this then I am getting response from api. But I am hard coding url and payload in axios.post.

Now if I pass value url and payload in it:

```
export default {
  post: async (
    url: string,
    payload = {},
  ): Promise<any> => {      
    payload = getPayload(payload);
        console.log("url: ",url)
        console.log("payload: ", payload);
        
    axios.post(url, payload)
        .then((resp: any)=> {
            console.log("resp here: ",JSON.stringify(resp.data));;
            
        })
        .catch((err: any)=> {
            console.log("err here: ", err);
            
        });
    // return getRequestPromise(request);
  },
};
```

Then I am getting error:

```
err here:  [Error: Network Error]
```

I did console for url and payload to check if they are coming correctly or not:

```
 LOG  url:   https://url.com/user/login
 LOG  payload:  {"email": "email@gmail.com", "password": "123456"}
```

this is the same which when I hard code inside axios.post then resp is coming.

I don't understand what is the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure the logged values are a 100% correct? Not maybe some additional whitespace anywhere (which could be hard to spot in console, but could easily "invalidate" the whole URL to begin with.)

Comment: What’s “getPayload”? I mean… If it works hard-coded then either the url or payload isn’t what you think it is. If “getPayload” is async that’s another issue; the console log will be updated after the async function completes—you can log the stringified payload to eliminate this issue.

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much. such a silly mistake from my side. I wasted 2 hours of work trying to find the issue